# Blackberry 10 compilation error on the default "Hello World' Sample

Tags: c++, blackberry-10

Hello I am new to Blackberry 10 development and after trying to compile my first "Hello World" application which comes as default with the package I get the following errors in the console. I am running windows 8 64 bit.
Please note I didn't make any changes to the default "Hello World" template which comes with the ndk.

Below are the contents of my main.cpp file:

```
// Default empty project template
#include <bb/cascades/Application>

#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>
#include "applicationui.hpp"

// include JS Debugger / CS Profiler enabler
// this feature is enabled by default in the debug build only
#include <Qt/qdeclarativedebug.h>

    using namespace bb::cascades;

    Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    // this is where the server is started etc
    Application app(argc, argv);

    // localization support
    QTranslator translator;
    QString locale_string = QLocale().name();
    QString filename = QString( "MyApp_%1" ).arg( locale_string );
    if (translator.load(filename, "app/native/qm")) {
        app.installTranslator( &translator );
    }

    new ApplicationUI(&app);

    // we complete the transaction started in the app constructor and start the client event loop here
    return Application::exec();
    // when loop is exited the Application deletes the scene which deletes all its children (per qt rules for children)
}
```

This is the console output:

```
../precompiled.h:1:0: fatal error: can't open "C:\Users\Tich Kames\AppData\Local\Temp\2qccKaF3bb\precompiled.s" for writing: Invalid argument
make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Tich Kames/ndk-10.1.0-workspace/MyApp/arm'
compilation terminated.
cc: C:/bbndk/host_10_1_0_132/win32/x86/usr/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0eabi/4.6.3/cc1plus caught signal 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Tich Kames/ndk-10.1.0-workspace/MyApp/arm'
make[2]: *** [o.le-v7-g/.obj/MyApp.gch/c++] Error 1
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make: *** [Device-Debug] Error 2
```

Comment: You should add your code to the question

Comment: You should try to create another windows user without spaces in the name and reinstall everything in it

Comment: Hie Thanks Hithredin. I created a new windows user account and it worked fine. Its definitely the spaces I had.

Comment: Great! I'll post this as answer

Answer (score 1):

As aknowledged by tkames, the problem comes from the spaces in the workspace and temp path.